# ASP.NET routing on IIS 6 Compiled web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

HI I have a web application and I'm using asp.net routing. When I publish it with the **Only files needed to run this application** selected it gives me an error when I'm loading any of the page "HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found."

but if I choose publish **All files** it works fine.

Do you know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: How is your environment set up, for instance, you dev machine, is that using IIS7, or Casini?

Comment: Dev machine is using iis 7, Producction iis 6

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same thing happens when you change **BuildAction** property of .aspx pages from Content to None or something else.

Comment: Set the BuildAction property of the affected pages to Content.

Comment: Ok I'm going to try it now. So far most of the pages Build Action set to Content. Do i need to set "Copy to output directory" to copy always?

Comment: Considering the Output Directory is implicitly the 'Bin' directory, you should leave aspx files set to "Do not copy".

Comment: no it is not working for me. I checked all pages and Build Action set to Content. It should be something else.

Comment: Are you sure that the ASP ISAPI module even processes the HTTP requests?
Code files (.cs) should not matter in deployment. Check what files got copied when using "All files" option (especially *.asax, *.ashx, *.config).

Comment: When I'm deploying all files (all files in project got copied) site working.